# playing a video on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a jQuery website, and I have a video as background. When somebody clicks on an div, I want the video to start, play for a few seconds; and then pause again.

I have this code now: But it starts to play directly when I open the page.

jQuery:

```
 $('#left').click(function () {
     $('#left').animate({
         width: '100%'
     }, 1000);
     $('#right').animate({
         width: '0%',
     }, 1000);
     $("#left").css("cursor", "auto");
     $("#right").css("cursor", "pointer");
     $('#videot').get(0).play();
 });
```

HTML:

```
<video preload="auto" class="videot" id="videot" height="100%" autoplay loop preload>
    <source src="BESTANDEN/film.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    <source src="videos/clouds.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
    <source src="videos/clouds.webm" type="video/webm" >
    <object data="film.mp4" height="1080">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="autoplay" value="true" >
        <param name="loop" value="true" >
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Just remove the autoplay attribute.

Comment: Hmmm... you really can't work that one out for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `autoplay` value  `false`

`<param name="autoplay" value="false" >` or remove it

```
<video preload="auto" class="videot" id="videot" height="100%" autoplay loop preload>
    <source src="BESTANDEN/film.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    <source src="videos/clouds.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
    <source src="videos/clouds.webm" type="video/webm" >
    <object data="film.mp4" height="1080">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="autoplay" value="false" ><!-- set false or remove it -->
        <param name="loop" value="true" >
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: woow, that I just didn't noticed that.. haha, thanks.